# Can I debug PHP scripts running in Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, php, debug

Coming from the Microsoft world, where Visual Studio, Windows, and IIS seemingly play nice together, I can attach the Visual Studio debugger to the IIS process and debug code in play.  When a web service call is made to the IIS server, I can evaluate the parameters, and watch the code execute.

Can I do the same with PHP scripts running in Apache on Ubuntu?  I have PHP5 on Apache2 and have installed xdebug.  PHPINFO() seems to think this is all setup and ready, only I have no idea how to attach this debugger to the httpd process and/or which editor/IDE to use to view the debugging.

Comment: did you read this [manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser plugin for Firefox called firePHP to debug php along with editing it "in play".   I am not entirely sure if Chrome has a similar plugin, but I'm going to lean towards yes.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firephp/

You could also install Netbeans and use that as your IDE.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Comment: So, if I understand your answer, you don't use the IDE to debug, you use a browser?

Comment: You can use either Netbeans or firephp to debug.